# Does Android 4.2 support IPsec IKEv2?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, vpn

Does Android 4.2 support IPsec [IKEv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange)?

If not, does any other version of Android support IPsec IKEv2?

Comment: Being a strong supporter of the [AAAAA](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/AAAAA), I took the freedom to link your abbreviation to an explanation. Hopefully I've picked the right one...

Comment: Android 11 is slated to be the first release to include support for IKEv2. There are some comments from a Strongswan developer about the implementation in the preview build here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225383/3183

Answer (score 6):

No Android version natively supports IKEv2 yet. But you can install the free and open-source [strongSwan VPN Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.strongswan.android) that uses IKEv2 and runs on Android 4 and newer.

Comment: Does it work with a non-rooted device?  Once installed and appropriately configured with IKEv2, is it otherwise functionally equivalent to the native VPN feature?

Comment: The app uses the [VpnService API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) so it should run on most devices without having to root them. There are some differences in the feature set, for instance, the always-on VPN feature provided by the native client on Android 4.2 and newer is not supported (but the app tries to keep the connection up once it has been established).