# How do I connect to a MSCHAPv2 VPN?

Tags: vpn

I can connect to my Office VPN. The config screens look like this (see images).

I am running Android 11 on a Pixel 2XL.

When I try to add the VPN details, I can't get it to work. Is it because I can't use MSCHAPv2? Am I missing something?
(The main config screen only has the login name, that's it)

[image]

Comment: Could you mention the device model and Android version? AFAIK, [MSCHAPv2 support is pretty new; since Android 11](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225383/44325).

Comment: Done! Thank you....

Comment: So... Can't be done?